# How to get value stored in browser from cross domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, browser

I need to obtain the value that I show in the image, it is stored in the STORAGE and it comes from
the following URL https://cdn.sat.gob.gt, my application is running at https://localhost:49955/

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1: Place this file on the remote domain that you want to get storage from**

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- Copyright 2010 Nicholas C. Zakas. All rights reserved. BSD Licensed. -->
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){

    //allowed domains
    var whitelist = ["foo.example.com", "www.example.com"];

    function verifyOrigin(origin){
        var domain = origin.replace(/^https?:\/\/|:\d{1,4}$/g, "").toLowerCase(),
            i = 0,
            len = whitelist.length;

        while(i < len){
            if (whitelist[i] == domain){
                return true;
            }
            i++;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function handleRequest(event){
        if (verifyOrigin(event.origin)){
            var data = JSON.parse(event.data),
                value = localStorage.getItem(data.key);
            event.source.postMessage(JSON.stringify({id: data.id, key:data.key, value: value}), event.origin);
        }
    }

    if(window.addEventListener){
        window.addEventListener("message", handleRequest, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent){
        window.attachEvent("onmessage", handleRequest);
    }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Step 2: Add this javascript file to the domain that you want to use to retrieve remote local storage**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2010 Nicholas C. Zakas. All rights reserved.
 * BSD Licensed.
 */
function CrossDomainStorage(origin, path){
    this.origin = origin;
    this.path = path;
    this._iframe = null;
    this._iframeReady = false;
    this._queue = [];
    this._requests = {};
    this._id = 0;
}

CrossDomainStorage.prototype = {

    //restore constructor
    constructor: CrossDomainStorage,

    //public interface methods

    init: function(){

        var that = this;

        if (!this._iframe){
            if (window.postMessage && window.JSON && window.localStorage){
                this._iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                this._iframe.style.cssText = "position:absolute;width:1px;height:1px;left:-9999px;";
                document.body.appendChild(this._iframe);

                if (window.addEventListener){
                    this._iframe.addEventListener("load", function(){ that._iframeLoaded(); }, false);
                    window.addEventListener("message", function(event){ that._handleMessage(event); }, false);
                } else if (this._iframe.attachEvent){
                    this._iframe.attachEvent("onload", function(){ that._iframeLoaded(); }, false);
                    window.attachEvent("onmessage", function(event){ that._handleMessage(event); });
                }
            } else {
                throw new Error("Unsupported browser.");
            }
        }

        this._iframe.src = this.origin + this.path;

    },

    requestValue: function(key, callback){
        var request = {
                key: key,
                id: ++this._id
            },
            data = {
                request: request,
                callback: callback
            };

        if (this._iframeReady){
            this._sendRequest(data);
        } else {
            this._queue.push(data);
        }   

        if (!this._iframe){
            this.init();
        }
    },

    //private methods

    _sendRequest: function(data){
        this._requests[data.request.id] = data;
        this._iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data.request), this.origin);
    },

    _iframeLoaded: function(){
        this._iframeReady = true;

        if (this._queue.length){
            for (var i=0, len=this._queue.length; i < len; i++){
                this._sendRequest(this._queue[i]);
            }
            this._queue = [];
        }
    },

    _handleMessage: function(event){
        if (event.origin == this.origin){
            var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            this._requests[data.id].callback(data.key, data.value);
            delete this._requests[data.id];
        }
    }

};
```

**Step 3: Then when you want to get remote local storage use this javascript**

```
var remoteStorage = new CrossDomainStorage("http://www.example.com", "/util/server.htm");

remoteStorage.requestValue("keyname", function(key, value){
    alert("The value for '" + key + "' is '" + value + "'");
});
```

---

I originally said it's not possible and @Efrain Mejias C corrected me.

https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/ is the solution.

BUT... I strongly believe that cross domain local storage data evaluation comes with some serious security concerns.

A source url can be spoofed and storage can be stuffed if someone wants to be malicious.

Despite the fact that it is possible... I personally wouldn't do this.

If you do implement this... be prepared for XSS attacks.

Comment: look this link : https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/

Comment: Well I'll be damned... someone built a library to get around it. Doesn't change the fact that cross domain local storage evaluation on the client side opens you up to some serious security concerns.

Comment: Can someone help me build this..I don't know JS well...please

Comment: I updated my answer with example code for you to use